# mySQL all categories query in select statement

Tags: php, mysql

I've got table of categories:

```
Id category
1  cat 1
2  cat 2
3  cat 3 
etc.
```

I want to make select statement with category variable in php: $category with PDO:

for example:

```
$category = 1;

$this->db->query('SELECT (...)
       WHERE category.id = :category');
$this->db->bind(':category', $category);
$results = $this->db->resultset();
```

How can I make that if ($category = 0) all categories will be selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code

```
$category = 1;

$str = '';
if(!empty($category)) $str = " WHERE category.id = :category";

$this->db->query('SELECT (...)
       '.$str);

if(!empty($category))
$this->db->bind(':category', $category);
$results = $this->db->resultset();
```

Comment: Have you read OPs question carefully? _I don't want to make if statement_ !

Comment: @B001 no - it's all right, this is the code, I asked for. Thank you so much. I didn't want to use if statement to prevent many sql queries.

Comment: it's upto you whether you want to use if statement or want to increase the unnecessary lines of code! If you got the your expected answer hope you will accept answer

Comment: @gileneusz next time please stay stable saying things and make clear what you really want...you see because of your vague statement pravindot17 got downvotes, so go and vote for them and accept answer

Comment: @B001 I'm sorry, I'm just beginner

Comment: I balanced the down vote and did an edit on the question and mark this as the best answer because it solved your problem. @gileneusz if can accept the edit.

Comment: @gileneusz _I'm just beginner_ Beginner in asking questions? I don't think so. How ever you don't need to apologize ;) Just do it better next time

Comment: @B001 I'm trying to be better every single day, thank you :)